# Как изменить размер QCheckBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, checkbox, qss

Как изменить вот эту часть `checkbox` ?

```
self.CB_30min = QCheckBox("15 мин", self)
self.CB_30min.move(310, 110)
self.CB_30min.resize(91, 31)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        cb = QCheckBox('Show title', self)
        cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        vbox.addWidget(cb)

    def changeTitle(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle('Hrllo Worjd')


StyleSheet = '''
QCheckBox {
    spacing: 5px;
    font-size:25px;     
}

QCheckBox::indicator {
    width:  33px;
    height: 33px;
}
'''            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")                 
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(300, 200)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```
self.CB_30min = QCheckBox("15 мин", self)
self.CB_30min.move(310, 110)
self.CB_30min.setStyleSheet("""QCheckBox::indicator {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}""")
self.CB_30min.resize(91, 31)
```

Comment: я наверное не верно выразил свою мысль. Хотелось бы увеличить область, где отображается "галочка"

Answer (score -1):

При помощи [Qt style sheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-checkbox)

```
QCheckBox::indicator {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Alexander Chernin, выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса

Comment: Извините, что 'передираю' ваш ответ, но мой понятней.